# android alert box with multiple options, how to use those options?

Tags: java, android, alert, dialog

I am a beginner, so if anyone would help me out. I created a list in the dialogue box , now how do i use those options? Like click one and it does something , click another and it does something else.

```
  CharSequence features[] = new CharSequence[] {"Save", "Send", "Something", "Something"};
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
         alertDialog.setTitle("Options");
         alertDialog.setItems(features, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Eta chu ma aile",
                          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });
                     alertDialog.show();

              return true; 
              }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know exact position of every item, just compare it with `which` param.

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    if (which == 0) {
       // handle "Save" option
    } else if (which == 1) {
       // handle "Send" option
    } ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use following code:
Somewhere in another function:
    String title = "My Alert Box";
    String msg = "Choose Option";
    alertfunc(title,msg);

The main alert function:

```
private void alertfunc(String title, String msg) {
    if (title.equals(TASK_VIEW_PROFILE)) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(msg)
                .setPositiveButton("Save",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                //Do something
                            }

                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Send",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) 
                            {
                                //Do something
                            }
                        }).create().show();
                .setNegativeButton("Something",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) 
                            {
                                //Do something
                            }
                        }).create().show();
                         //...and so on
    }
}
```